# How can I fix this hose winder?

Tags: hose

I inherited one of those nifty hose winder reel things that make storing your hoses really easy. However, this one seems slightly broken. There's a black plastic part that you screw your input hose into that fits onto the reel, like so:

[image]

However, it pulls right out; there doesn't seem to be anything actually holding it in place.

The black plastic thing that you connect the hose to says to "pull tabs on out tube" but I don't see any tabs anywhere to pull.

[image]

Here's the thing the black plastic part fits into:

[image]

Is it just broken? Would it be the end of the world if I superglued or epoxied the black plastic thing into the unit itself to prevent it from coming out?

Comment: "Super glue" or epoxy are not compatible with the types of plastic used in these hose winders.

Comment: What kind of glue will do it? Or is glue the wrong approach?

Comment: You should try the Plastic Weld that was suggested in @BrownRedHawk's answer. Whilst I have no direct experience with this JB product it appears targeted at this type of plastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though the portion that pulls out has sheared off from the inside. If you inherited this piece, I'm assuming you don't want to put much in it.

Clean it VERY well with some alcohol or similar (not acetone) and a brush. I'd try some J.B. Plastic Weld, let it setup and cure overnight and give it a shot. You've got a 50/50 chance it will either fail incredibly or someone will inherit it from you.

I've never had much luck with repairing things like this, but the J.B. Plastic Weld (and similar "plastic weld" products has fixed a veritable stable of Fisher Price toys, Big Wheels and similar.

Good luck!

Comment: Along with cleaning it may be a good suggestion to provide some lubricant to the flexible seal in the joint.

Comment: If you are going to lubricate, make sure to use vegetable or mineral oil, just about everything else will dissolve what remaining plastic you have.

Comment: I totally agree that the right lube need to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull apart the reel assembly (where the hose is wound around). Inside, you will find the tabs on the "out tube". Then you pull out the "out tube", and you can lock them together again. The best instructions I found are for a repair kit (no longer available) from amazon. Zoom in on the instructions to see the steps involved. https://www.amazon.ca/Suncast-Replacement-0461685a-JTT175B-SFB200B/dp/B003M5GSVU